# Session is null when i ajax post to a controller/action

Tags: c#, ajax, session, model-view-controller

I'm doing a Login with ajax.

The Login is a PartialView,have a Captcha-image which is a controller/action  and not a PartialView in it.

In the Captcha action,i use Session[key] = Captcha to save the Captcha.

When i post the form to the Login action with ajax, i check the Captcha in the Session, but the Session is null!

so, is there anyone konws what's wrong and give me a help to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I solve this now.

you just add

protected void Session_Start()
{ }

protected void Session_End()
{ }

in the Global.asax can fix this.

The reason is if you don't add Session_Start() and Session_End(),the C# MVC will create a new sessionid for every request.

So, the session you wanted is null.(because you got a new sessionid).